# How to access array field name value in the validation callback function?

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter, frameworks

I got some text inputs in my view:

```
<label for="car-n">Car Name:</label><input type="text" name="cars[]" id="car-n"/>
<label for="car-t">Car Type:</label><input type="text" name="cars[]" id="car-t"/>
```

And now, I would like to validate them with the CodeIgniter's validation callback function, but it seems like I can not get their values:

`$this->form_validation->set_rules('cars[]', 'Cars', 'required|xss_clean|callback__validate_cars');`

... and the function:

```
function _validate_cars($input)
{
     echo $input; //returns no field value;
     echo $this->form_validation->set_value('cars[]'); //not works
}
```

So, how should I access those two field values in my callback function then? I havent seen any informations about this case in the CodeIgniters user guide.

Comment: I didn't used codeigniter but did you tried `$this->form_validation->set_rules('cars', 'Cars', 'required|xss_clean|callback__validate_cars');` ? Note this missing of `[]`

Comment: you can access to the post data with `$this->input->post('cars')` into your function

Comment: I know this could be stupid, but you have a double `_` in the function name, should be `callback_validate_cars` instead of `callback__validate_cars`. Ignore me if you are over the case :)

Comment: @manix You're right, but for some reason ... the output of the `print_r($this->input->post('cars'))` are two identical arrays (instead of one): `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => test) Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => test)`

Comment: This have no sence, can you post all your controller? (at least the validator function)

Comment: @manix This have sence, because there are two fields with the same name, but thats the only sense I see. Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2v6R6BKi (sorry for the code formatting).

Comment: @Scott, calling `print_r($this->input->post('cars')` inside of call function will be print it twice because the form_validation library call this function several times. Look this [Test controller code](https://gist.github.com/3929928)

Comment: @manix Oh, thats a good news then...

Comment: @manix Not really, it just "works" (although I still don't like how CI running the callback function twice)... You can post an answer related to what you wrote in your comments and I will accept with a pleasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, look the controller below:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Temp extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library(array('form_validation'));
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->show_form();
    }



    public function validate(){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cars[]', 'Cars', 'required|callback_validate_cars');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->show_form();

        }
        else "All is ok";
    }

    public function validate_cars($string)
    {
        print_r($this->input->post('cars'));
        return false;
    }

    public function show_form()
    {
        echo '<form action="'. base_url('temp/validate').'" method="post">';
        echo 'Car 1: <input name="cars[]" type="text">';
        echo ' Car 2: <input name="cars[]" type="text">';
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Go!">';
        echo '</form';
    }
}
```

You can use the post value as `$this->input->post('cars');`